# Navigation-based app using buttons instead of a table?

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm writing my first iPhone application and have worked my way through some books.

I'm working on a navigation-based app, and I was wondering:

(1) Is it possible to use buttons instead of a table to activate the navigation?

(2) If so, how do I add the little disclosure indicators to a button? And how do I make the buttons look a bit more fancy than a rounded rect button (e.g. make the button colored and glossy)?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes it is possible to navigate using buttons. See [`-[UINavigationController pushViewController:animated:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UINavigationController)
2. You can use [`+[UIButton buttonWithType:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html) and specify `UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure` for a disclosure button. As for colored and glossy buttons they are not supported in the current SDK (ios 4), but you can use a custom glossy and colored image or implement your own drawing code (see below for link).

Here is an [article from Cocoa with Love](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/09/drawing-gloss-gradients-in-coregraphics.html) about creating glossy buttons.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I tried to set a button to be a DetailDisclosure button through Interface Builder, but the entire button became an arrow. Is there a way to get a button with text and an arrow, similar to how it's rendered in a table cell, like "Foobar >"?

Comment: You will need to use the custom button type and supply a custom image. I wish it were easier. You could place a label next to it if that would meet your requirements

Comment: Do you know of any online instructions for creating a custom button type with custom image? I just googled for that but could only find some Youtube tutorial videos.